# click() Event in javascript with a PARAM?

Tags: javascript, click

I'm using the event click() to call a method in Code Behind, like this:

HTML

```
<asp:button bordercolor="White" id="btnAddGS" onclick="AddGSBandeira" runat="server">
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnAddGS").click();
```

C#

```
public void AddGSBandeira(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Its work normally, but I need to pass a param in the javascript call, like this:

$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnAddGS").click("param");

But I do not know how this works ...can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is create a hidden control and populate it's value with JavasScript on the click event. Your code behind will be able to access that value on your postback (AJAX or otherwise).

**Markup**

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="myHiddenField" runat="server" />
<asp:button bordercolor="White" id="btnAddGS" 
            onclick="AddGSBandeira" 
            onclientclick="SetHiddenValue()" runat="server">
```

**JavaScript**

```
function SetHiddenValue()
{
    document.getElementById("<%=myHiddenField.ClientID%>").value = "[Your value here]";
}
```

**C#**

```
public void AddGSBandeira(object sender, EventArgs e){}
{
    var jsVal = myHiddenField.Value;
}
```

Comment: the problem is, that I have an ID in the javascript.. And this ID i need in my Codebehind.. So how I can give this ID from JS to Codebehind, to work with it?

Comment: you can access it in code behind like that: `myHiddenField.Value`

Comment: @Fender, as stated in my post :)

Comment: I think comments should be blocked while edits are being made :)

Comment: finally got it, it worked.. i tried it he whole time with a <asp:hiddenfield>.. i didnt work, so I took a normal HTML hiddenfield and it worked, thx 4 answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `trigger`.

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnAddGS").trigger("click",["param"]);
```

I believe the 2nd parameter to trigger should be an array of arguments to pass to the function.

Comment: thx for your answer! But how can I handle this Param from my Method in the CodeBehind? protected void button_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e, int param){} ??

Comment: @Fender I don't agree with you. kingjiv has offered an alternative way to reach the goal from eMi.

Comment: @reporter: this does not pass a parameter to the **server side** function. it passes a parameter to the client side click function and this is not what eMi wants